# Execute users default shell in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, macos

In a shell script I'd like to execute the users shell and continue the script once the shell finishes.

It should look something like this:

```bsh
> myScript.sh
Script ouput
> echo "shell started by myScript.sh"
shell started by myScript.sh
> exit
More script output
>
```

It works when I execute a shell in the script:

```bsh
echo "Script output"
bash
echo "More script output"
```

But I'd like it not to use a fixed shell. The users login shell or the shell he was in before he started myScript.sh whould be fine.

Any solution must work not only on Linux-based systems but also Mac OSX

Comment: Does `$SHELL` hold the value you're looking for

Comment: @roaima that's exactly what I need. And simple. Care to make an answer of it? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$SHELL` environment variable (if it's set)

```
echo "Script output"
"${SHELL-bash}"
echo "More script output"
```

In this instance if it's unset the code will call `bash`.

I haven't checked it points to a valid executable, on the assumption that if someone has fiddled with it they will affect quite a number of other applications too, but as it's supposed to be a full path you could use this type of approach (untested)

```
[ -n "$SHELL" ] && [ -x "$SHELL" ] || SHELL=
"${SHELL-bash}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial login shell is saved in the passwd database, so you can do something along the lines of `$(getent passwd myusername | cut -d: -f7)`. Note that if, say, I usually use `zsh`, but currently am in a `bash` and run this, I will get a `zsh` and not a `bash`, which may or may not be what you want?

Comment: I think the usecase that the user changes the shell will be seldom. And I don‘t think there is a right or wrong in this case. So, whatever is easiest.

Comment: bash: getent: command not found. Doesn't work on MacOS. I'm loking for a method that works on both Linux & MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable `$$` refers to the current PID. We can use this with 'ps' to find the current shell:

`ps --no-header -o args -p $$ | cut -d- -f2`

Above should return what you want, trimming the leading - which may be present. Eg:

```bsh
THESHELL=`ps --no-header -o args -p "$$" | cut -d- -f2`
start_another_shell() {
    "$THESHELL"
}
echo "The shell is $THESHELL"
start_another_shell
echo "Bye!"
```

Make sure to run it with "source" to avoid accidentally forkbombing yourself. Eg:

```bsh
me@here$ source myScript
The shell is bash
me@here$ exit
Bye!
$ zsh
$ source myScript
The shell is zsh
$ exit
Bye!
```

Comment: ps: illegal option -- -
Doesn't seem to work on MacOS

Comment: Using `ps -o args= -p "$$" | cut -d- -f2` works on Linux & MacOS

Comment: ```cut -d-``` is used because we're using "-" as the delimiter, not ' '. It's there because we might get something like ```-zsh```. And the forkbomb isn't likely; I just wanted to prevent the script recursively calling itself. Good point about the quotes though, edited!